# How do I delete a file?

Tags: file, delphi, delphi-xe2, delete-file

I need to delete a picture from a folder where pictures are stored. For example, a file in the C:\Milk\Pictures folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the SysUtils function [DeleteFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.DeleteFile):

```
if DeleteFile(FileName) then
  // File deleted;
```

`SysUtils` is usually included by default. In XE2, if you have to add it you may have to use `System.SysUtils` because of new namespace rules.

Comment: Is there any need to add something in the uses section

Comment: Not in XE2. `SysUtils` is included by default usually, but I gave you the unit name in my answer. In XE2, you may have to use `System.SysUtils` because of new namespace rules. :-) If that doesn't solve it, you're missing some information in your question. What problem are you having using it?

Comment: You do not have to specify the `System` namespace in code if it is specified in the "Unit scope names" field of the Project Options (which is where it should be).

Comment: Thereby my statement about **may** have to use and not **have** to use. :-)